# What is the small edit widget shown in LXDE on Openbox?

Tags: lxde, openbox

When I start typing but no application has focus, a small window is displayed in the corner of the desktop. Any ideas what it is and what can it be used for? Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> just closes it.
[image]

Writing a command inside it has no effects (I tried with `/usr/bin/xterm` which normally starts an xterm, and with `/usr/bin/touch /home/choroba/ABCD`, but the file wasn't created).

Comment: Huh... I thought I knew everything an end-user could know about LXDE and this is entirely new to me. Never noticed it before. Quite some time ago, there was some discussion about adding a search functionality to LXDE and this may be an artifact of that. I don't have any older versions to check against to see when it appeared. If you don't get an answer here, you may want to try their [mailing lists](http://lxde.sourceforge.net/contact.html) to ask the devs directly.

Comment: can you use `xprop` utility to get some info about this window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the search box of PCManFM file manager.

- The text in it is used to locate a file by file name.

  - The first matched file will be selected automatically, so that when you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the selected file will be opened/issued, and the search box will be closed.
  - If no file matched (like your case), then no file will be selected, press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will just close the search box.
  - The file name matching logic seems to be:

    `"file name"`.startsWith (`"text in search box"`)
- After a short time with no key input, this search box will be closed.

[image: search box in Desktop]

[image: search box in PCManFM file manager]

I saw a search box in Caja file manager too, but search box will not shown when typing in the desktop (MATE Desktop).

Comment: Nice. It works if I have files on my desktop (I never do) but didn't seem to do anything with pcmanfm - though it could be my dark theme hiding any highlighting.